# How to filter by namespace in Fluentd

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

In my application Fluend, I need to send log to graylog filter by Namespace. Theres a filter or something that helps?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)